# How to terminate an infinite process with an specific time duration

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I tried to run hundreds of commands in a batch.

So I have to let each command can be terminated under an duration, and then executes the next.

However, the command will be terminated, because the timeout option argument is not working for `ffmpeg`

So I wonder is there any workaround  that can terminate an command within an time duration.

I can terminate the command (which is running in foreground) by type 'q'

```
def get_video_clip(self, rtsp_link="rtsp://localhost:554", f_name="sample", period=5):
        cmd = "ffmpeg -i {0} -acodec copy -vcodec copy {1}.mp4 -t {2}".format(  rtsp_link,
                                                                                f_name,
                                                                                period
                                                                                )
        ap(cmd)

        os.popen(cmd)
        pass
```

I attempted to capture streaming via rtsp and limit the clip duration under `3 sec`

But the option doesn't work. The ffmpeg won't be terminated anymore.

Is there any workaround to fix the problem.

Because I have to run hundreds of similar commands in a batch with Python script.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel verbose   -i rtsp://172.19.1.42/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy  c0_s1_h264_640x480_30_vbr_500_99_40000000.mp4 -timeout 3 -y
```

> $ ffmpeg -h ffmpeg version 1.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg
>   developers   built on Nov 22 2013 11:59:59 with Apple LLVM version 5.0
>   (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

The detailed log at  https://gist.github.com/poc7667/8234701

Comment: Not really a solution for your problen, but... did you read the `os.open` docs? *Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the subprocess module.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ThiefMaster mentioned, you can use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), which provides both `poll` (to check whether the process is terminated) and a `communicate` method (to send data to the subprocess stdin).

Something along these lines:

```
# Starts encoding in a subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-i' 'myinput', 'myoutput'])

duration = 3
sleeptime = 0
while proc.poll() is None and sleeptime < 3: 
    # Wait for the specific duration or for the process to finish
    sleep(1)
    sleeptime += 1

# If process is not terminated
if proc.poll() is None:
    # Cancels process, waits for it to complete
    proc.communicate("q")
```

Will cancel the subprocess if it has not finished within the specified `duration`.

Comment: Why would sending a "q" quits the process?

Comment: That is a feature of `ffmpeg`. It is not valid in the general case though.